# Problem in Bind with 4 views

Tags: freebsd, bind, jails

I have Bind server installed on FreeBSD Jails. I have master and two slaves. And I have 4 views for different locations. When I add some record on master zone and type `rndc reload` I see that all 4 views send updates:

```
25-Apr-2017 17:41:19.112 general: info: zone abc.am/IN/internal: loaded serial 2017042502
25-Apr-2017 17:41:19.112 notify: info: zone abc.am/IN/internal: sending notifies (serial 2017042502)
25-Apr-2017 17:41:19.113 general: info: zone abc.am/IN/external: loaded serial 2017042502
25-Apr-2017 17:41:19.113 notify: info: zone abc.am/IN/external: sending notifies (serial 2017042502)
25-Apr-2017 17:41:19.115 general: info: zone abc.am/IN/armenia: loaded serial 2017042502
25-Apr-2017 17:41:19.115 notify: info: zone abc.am/IN/armenia: sending notifies (serial 2017042502)
25-Apr-2017 17:41:19.116 general: info: zone abc.am/IN/notarmenia: loaded serial 2017042502
25-Apr-2017 17:41:19.116 notify: info: zone abc.am/IN/notarmenia: sending notifies (serial 2017042502)
```

But from the slave side I see that only internal zone is updated:

```
25-Apr-2017 17:41:19.317 general: info: zone abc.am/IN/internal: transferred serial 2017042502: TSIG 'internal.ns.zone'
25-Apr-2017 17:41:19.317 notify: info: zone abc.am/IN/internal: sending notifies (serial 2017042502)
```

When I type for example `rndc retransfer abc.am IN external`, `rndc retransfer abc.am IN armenia` and `rndc retransfer abc.am IN notarmenia` I see that all 3 another zones are updated. I don't understand what the problem is. Any suggestion?

My views configuration are same:

**Master's view**

```
view external IN {
    notify yes;
    allow-query { INTERNAL_NS; TRUSTED_NS; };
    allow-transfer { key external.ns.zone.; };
    match-clients { key external.ns.zone.; localhost; localnets; } ;
    include "/usr/local/etc/namedb/conf/defaultzones.conf";
    include "/usr/local/etc/namedb/conf/masterzones.conf";
    include "/usr/local/etc/namedb/conf/slavezones.conf";
    include "/usr/local/etc/namedb/conf/reversemasters.conf";
    include "/usr/local/etc/namedb/conf/reverseslaves.conf";
    zone "abc.am" { type master; file "/usr/local/etc/namedb/master/abc.am.external"; };
};
```

**Slave's view**:

```
view external IN {
   match-clients { key external.ns.zone.; ABC_EXT; };
   allow-query { ABC_EXT; };
   server 10.16.16.201 { transfer-format many-answers; keys { external.ns.zone.; }; };
   include "/usr/local/etc/namedb/conf/defaultzones.conf";
   include "/usr/local/etc/namedb/conf/masterzones.conf";
   include "/usr/local/etc/namedb/conf/slavezones-ext.conf";
   include "/usr/local/etc/namedb/conf/reversemasters.conf";
   include "/usr/local/etc/namedb/conf/reverseslaves-ext.conf";
   zone "abc.am" {type slave; masters { NSMASTER; }; file "/usr/local/etc/namedb/slave/abc.am-view2"; };
};
```

Comment: Post the view configurations of the master and a slave.